# iPhone - ShareKit , SHK.m giving the compiler error for FileNot Found

Tags: iphone, compiler-errors, sharekit, file-not-found

I am facing the issue while compiling my iphone project with ShareKit Integrated .I was working on that , everything was working fine till now , all of a sudden now its giving me the error. In SHK.m file ,

```
  #import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h>  file not found
```

I guess I have accidentally changed something or deleted any file . Not getting what has happened wrong. Can anybody help me with this issue ??

Note : ( I have not changed my Xcode , nor the project location or anything )

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
    #import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h>
```

It has to be

```
        #import <objc/message.h> 
        #import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Answer (score 12):

Are you using xcode 4.3? if yes then just replace

```
#import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h>
```

this with `#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes new #import does solve the problem but give new error

```
file - New OAuth Web Service.m
file -  /shareKit/Template Src/ShareKit/New Web Service.m
file - /shareKit/Template Src/ShareKit/New Action.m

code - `«OPTIONALHEADERIMPORTLINE»`
error - Expected identifier or '('
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes new #import does solve the problem but give new error

**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Answer (score 0):

Import

#import  < Objc/message.h >

#import < objc/runtime.h >

Imstead OF

## import < /usr/include/objc/objc-class.h>

And Change the Deployment Target to 7.0 and It has worked for Me.