# ShareKit missing file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, social-networking

I have a perfect functioning app in xcode 4.

As soon as I add the frameworks and the shk folder to my project
I get 6 errors, first of them;

```
#import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h> file not found
```

I tried this

[iPhone - ShareKit , SHK.m giving the compiler error for FileNot Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310512/iphone-sharekit-shk-m-giving-the-compiler-error-for-filenot-found)

but still the same...

Regards
Mirza

Answer (score 5):

Are you using xcode 4.3? if yes then just replace

```
#import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h>
```

this with

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```